# dropcreatedatabasealways does not work, seed() method does not called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am sorry for my English. This is my first post-question. And I'm new in Web Development, Sorry. Please help.

I tried Code First.

In my MVC project with Individual User Account Authentication I created Model.

Then I created Context for this Model.

Then I created ContextInitializer which is inherited from DropCreateDatabaseAlways<> like

```
class MusicStoreDataContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MusicStoreDataContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MusicStoreDataContext context)
    {
        Artist artist = new Artist() { Name = "First Artist" };
        context.Artists.Add(artist);
        context.Albums.Add(new Album() { Artist = artist, Title = "First Album" });
        context.Albums.Add(new Album() { Artist = artist, Title = "Second Album" });
        context.Albums.Add(new Album()
        {
            Artist = context.Artists.Add(new Artist() { Name = "Second Artist" }),
            Title = "Third Album"
        });

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and then I inserted in Application_Start() in Global.Asax.cs file

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MusicStoreDataContextInitializer());
```

and My Seed() method does not work. When I put breakpoint in Seed() in Debug mode Program Flow does not enter in this Seed() method.

I tried do in Global.Asax.cs file something like

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MusicStoreDataContextInitializer());
MusicStoreDataContext db = new MusicStoreDataContext();
db.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Seed() does not called. And Table Information does not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand, the problem was using EF 6 and using Migrations with initializers. This was cause errors.

When I recreated my project without any

```
PM> Enable-Migration
```

commands in Package Manager Console everything became OK ).

And database recreated and seeded with new data.

If my experience will help Anybody, I will be happy.

Now I want to spent more time to Understand Migrations more deep.